# Actual procedure used to establish a MW link budget in telecom?

Tags: signal, communication, wireless, microwave, telecommunications

If it possible can someone share with me the actual procedure used  (Not the theoretical steps in book !) like in Huawei or others telecom vendor to establish a Microwave Link between to sites

Like the Software tool they use and actual parameters.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

If planning to deploy the communication scheme in a highly varied environment such as a city or town, ray-tracing techniques can be used. Ray-tracing is very computationally intensive and requires a lot of input parameters characterising the propagation environment such as a 3D topographical map of the area of concern (which can be hard to acquire).

Popular software tools used by mobile operators include the [Volcano](http://www.siradel.com/software/connectivity/volcano-software/) tool set from [Siradel](http://www.siradel.com/). From their website you can see that Volcano tool is used by over 100 mobile operators all over the world. In addition to this, the tool also used by the wireless research community.